# SQL Server : Reuse calculated variable in select clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have the following table structure:

```
col1     col2     col3    col4
-------------------------------
aK       Mbcd      ABc    defgh
```

`col2`, `col3` and `col4` columns are of type `varchar(100)` and `col1` has type `varchar(500)`.

I need a select query to have the output as following

```
col1    col2     col3    col4
-------------------------------
aK,Mb   cd,A      Bc,d    efgh
```

Logic is explained as mentioned below:

1. In the result, Col2, col3 and col4 can have maximum 4 characters but col1 can have more than 4 characters upto 100.
2. If any column has more characters, last 4 characters will be retained in the same column and other extra columns will be concatenated with previous column's value separated by comma **,** and the same rule will be applied on the concatenated values as well.

I've written the following T-SQL statement. It works fine for last two columns. But I want to use new calculated value of col3 to strip out extra characters after adding some from col4

```
SELECT
    CASE 
       WHEN X.Col4Length > 4 
          THEN concat(X.col3, ',', substring(x.col4, 0, X.Col4Length - 3))
          ELSE X.col3
    END AS col3,
    CASE 
       WHEN X.Col4Length > 4 
          THEN substring(x.col4, X.Col4Length - 3, x.Col4Length)
          ELSE X.col4
    END AS col4
FROM
    (SELECT
         Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4,
         Len(Col1) AS Col1Length,
         Len(Col2) AS Col2Length,
         Len(Col3) AS Col3Length,
         Len(Col4) AS Col4Length
     FROM       
         mytable) X
```

Comment: It seems like you're misusing SQL here - feels more like a presentation issue than a data one, per se, and so probably better dealt with in an application/reporting tool than in SQL. Also, obvious edge case - what if the total amount of text exceeds the capacities you've stated? E.g. input sizes are `(100,100,100,100)` and output sizes are `(100,4,4,4)`.

Comment: Ok thanks for pointing out another problem. I'll set col1  size to `500`

Answer (score 3):

My try with a simple sub-query

```
with t1 as (
select 'aK' col1, 'Mbcd' col2, 'ABc' col3, 'defgh' col4 
---
SELECT LEFT(col, LEN(col) - 12) col1,
      RIGHT(LEFT(col, LEN(col) - 8), 4) col2,
      RIGHT(LEFT(col, LEN(col) - 4), 4) col3,
      RIGHT(col, 4) AS col4
FROM
(
    SELECT col1+','+col2+','+col3+','+col4 AS col
    FROM t1
) t;
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to *reuse calculated variables*

There are two *set-based /inline / adhoc* approaches (and many more ugly procedural):

- `CTE`s to do this for the whole set in advance
- `CROSS APPLY` for the same on row level

Try it like this (CTE approach)

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(col1 VARCHAR(100),col2 VARCHAR(100),col3 VARCHAR(100),col4 VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 ('aK','Mbcd','ABc','defgh')
,('123456','abc','3456','123456789');

WITH ResolveCol4 AS
(
    SELECT *
          ,RIGHT(col4,4) AS Col4_resolved
          ,col3 + ',' + CASE WHEN LEN(col4)>4 THEN SUBSTRING(col4,1,LEN(col4)-4) ELSE '' END AS col3_New
    FROM @tbl
)
,ResolveCol3 AS
(
    SELECT *
          ,RIGHT(col3_New,4) AS Col3_resolved
          ,col2 + ',' + CASE WHEN LEN(col3_New)>4 THEN SUBSTRING(col3_New,1,LEN(col3_New)-4) ELSE '' END AS col2_New
    FROM ResolveCol4 
)
,ResolveCol2 AS
(
    SELECT *
          ,RIGHT(col2_New,4) AS Col2_resolved
          ,col1 + ',' + CASE WHEN LEN(col2_New)>4 THEN SUBSTRING(col2_New,1,LEN(col2_New)-4) ELSE '' END AS col1_New
    FROM ResolveCol3 
)
SELECT col1_new,Col2_resolved,Col3_resolved,Col4_resolved 
FROM ResolveCol2
```

The result

```
aK,Mb           cd,A    Bc,d    efgh
123456,abc,34   56,1    2345    6789
```